# Linq To SQL login failed after restore database

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, linq, database-restore

In my WPF application I need to backup and restore the database. everything is fine by backup, but when I restore the database, Linq to sql login failed and application crash (restore complete successfully, and then when try to use the restored database the exception about login failed raise).

I should mention that I'am using another database for restoring and backuping original database (when I try with the same one it raise database on use exception so I have to use another database).

Procedure for restoring database is like below :

```
BEGIN TRY
    ALTER DATABASE DatabaseName 
    SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
    RESTORE DATABASE DatabaseName FROM DISK = @Address WITH REPLACE , NOUNLOAD
    ALTER DATABASE DatabaseName
    SET ONLINE
    RETURN 1
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ALTER DATABASE DatabaseName
    SET ONLINE
    RETURN 0
END CATCH
```

And below is the code to call procedure:

```
using (DatabaseManagerDataContext db = new DatabaseManagerDataContext())
{
    int answer = db.Restore(RestoreFile); 
    if (answer == 1)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Everything fine and answer is 1 but after the above code when I am trying the restored database it raise login failed exception.

I've searched a lot but cannot find out what's wrong with it. Where am I wrong?

Scenario which cause the exception :

```
1. connecting to database using linq to sql (first connectionstring) and fetch some data from db
2. connecting to managerdatabase using linq to sql (second connectionstring) and restore backup with mentioned procedure
3. try to connect to database using linq to sql (first connectionstring) and fetch data (here is where it says: FAILED TO LOGIN)
```

P.S: I'm using two Linq to sql (2 .dbml file) for Database and DatabaseManager with below connection strings:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DatabaseConnectionString"
        connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Database;Integrated Security=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="DatabaseManagerConnectionString"
        connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=DatabaseManager;Integrated Security=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

### UPDATE

As nothing work (including detach and attach database), I give notification to user to run again the program and close it programatically.

Comment: Test database using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) which comes with SQL Server.  You can perform simple queries to determine if the issue is the database or c# application.  I suspect the credentials weren't set properly after the database was restored.  SSMS should determine if the credential are correct. Make sure you log into database with same credentials as your program.

Comment: @jdweng I don't have any problem when I execute procedure with ssms, the restore done correctly by the application too, and after crash when I run the application again everything is okey and can login correctly.

Comment: A you using any VIEWs as a temporary table?  You may need to manually drop the View from the database.  I have seen some cases where drop the View correct issue like this.  See : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173492.aspx

Comment: @jdweng No there is no VIEW in my database !

Comment: I still think it is a credential issue.  Normally you need an admin to restore the database using the commands posted.  For a non admin to add a database you  should use Attach.  The stored procedure is probably running as an admin while your c# is running as a users.  Try after restoring database from SSMS a Deattach and then an attach.  Then run c# application.  If this works then a user credential is wrong in the database.

Comment: @jdweng It doesn't need any detach and attach ! if I close c# application and run it again it work. so what is wrong with the credential? It's kind of problem with linq to reconnect to restored database middle of application running...

Comment: @Evil, what is the exact text of the login failed exception?  There may be additional information about failed login errors in the SQL Server error log.

Comment: Did you try to disconnected in c# and then reconnect?  Running the stored procedure I think is changing the credentials.

Comment: @DanGuzman the whole message is : "Additional information: Cannot open database 'DatabaseName' requested by the login. The login failed."

Comment: @jdweng I post the procedure where is changing the credential code? and if so, how to can I revert it?

Comment: Not sure.  I've seen SQL Server do unexpected things.  I would try in the procedure that does the restore to do a deattach and reattach.

Comment: @jdweng I can't understand, BTW thanks.

Comment: Add to code : EXEC sp_detach_db DatabaseName, 'true'; 
    CREATE DATABASE DatabaseName   
    ON (FILENAME = 'C:\MySQLServer\DatabaseName.mdf'),   
    (FILENAME = 'C:\MySQLServer\DatabaseName_Log.ldf')   
    FOR ATTACH;

Comment: @jdweng is there anyway to get address of database dynamically?

Comment: SqlConnection _conn = new SqlConnection("Server=.\\SQLExpress;Database=Test;Trusted_Connection=True;");
            _conn.Open();
            string SQL = "SELECT * FROM sys.database_files";
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(SQL, _conn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.AsEnumerable())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(row["physical_name"]);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();

Comment: @jdweng thanks but detach and attaching doesn't solve the problem ! I close the application and notify user to run again after restore ...

Comment: The query returns a number of parameters which may help determine cause of issue.  Check other fields/columns to see the status of the database.